# Finding a basis for $K \otimes V+V\otimes K$

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Hi I'm trying to find a basis for $K \otimes V + V \otimes K$ where $K = Span\{x \otimes y + y \otimes x \mid x,y \in V\} \subseteq V \otimes V$ and $V$ is an n dimensional vector space. So far I've managed to create some for when $n=2,3$ by taking the basis for $K \otimes V$ and adding in linearly independent elements from $V\otimes K$ but I'm struggling to extend it to general n. Any advice?

Comment: For have you worked out for, e.g., $\dim V = 3$?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean?

Comment: I mean, you've said you've constructed a basis in the special case $n = 3$, what is it?

Comment: Oh ok. Sure. So if $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is a basis for $V$, I constructed one for $K$ as (for short hand I'll write $v_i \otimes v_j = v_iv_j$) $v_1v_1,v_2v_2,v_3v_3,v_1v_2+v_2v_1,v_1v_3+v_3v_1,v_2v_3+v_3v_2$. I then constructed a basis for $K \otimes V$ by "adding" $v_i, i=1,2,3$ on the right of each of these terms and expanding brackets, ie $(v_1v_2+v_2v_1)v_3 = v_1v_2v_3+v_2v_1v_3$. I then did this similarly for $V \otimes K$ but on the left and then comparing what I had in the two  columns and removing elements that were not linearly independent. I hope this describes it?